# 4 player card game, who has advantage?

Tags: probability, cards

Edit for "off topic" "correction".

I don't know why this question was considered "off topic".  It seemed to draw a lot of attention.  The "puzzle" was to figure out which person has the advantage which is not obvious.  The pieces that need to be put together are the checks for each winner.

Also, if this type of question is "off topic", then why do they have both probability and card tags available on this site?  I used both of those tags to classify my question here.

Four people, (call them C, D, E and F), decide to play a card game for fun. They use an ordinary fair deck of $52$ cards, shuffled well immediately before each hand is drawn, and randomly draw cards from it one a time without replacement, all 4 using (sharing) the same drawn cards to determine who wins. A win is defined as follows:

C wins if he gets at least one of all $13$ ranks of the cards (regardless of suit as they can be mixed suits or even all the same suit).

D wins if he gets either $6$ red cards or $6$ black cards in a row (consecutive).

E wins if she gets $4$ of a kind of ANY ONE odd rank ($A,3,5,7,9,J,K$).

F wins if she gets at least $12$ black cards and at least $12$ red cards.

Each win is based on the current hand only as there is no "carryover" from a previous hand. Each new hand starts "fresh".

It is possible for ties to occur but the rule is any and all ties are awarded as a half win for D and a half win for E. That is, if each player bet 1 dollar for a hand so that there were 4 dollars in the pot for that hand, D and E would split any ties so that they would get 2 dollars each. Note that D and E split ANY ties so even if only C and F tie, they both lose and D and E split the pot with a half win each.

So the question is who has the highest probability of winning and by how much over the competition?

Note that the minimum # of cards needed to win differs for each player:

(C: $13$),  (D: $6$),  (E: $4$), (F: $24$).

Another game rule is if nobody wins by the $28$th card drawn in the hand, then that hand has no winner and a new hand will be drawn.  That is, $28$ cards max will be drawn per hand.

F.Y.I., my simulation has lots of "buckets" to count up interesting things and the most rare thing I see (that shows up as nonzero) out of $10,000,000$ iterations is D and E tying in only $8$ cards drawn.  This is not a "bonus" tie because neither C nor F can tie with only $8$ cards drawn.  It is so rare that out of $10$ million decisions, only $29$ were ties between D and E with exactly $8$ cards drawn.  That one special case can probably be calculated mathematically since there are only $52 \choose 8$ card combos which is about $3/4$ billion.  Even simulation of all of those hands is possible on a computer to get the exact count of winners.

$UPDATE:$ I am curious about how many actual ways there are for D and E to tie in exactly $8$ cards since it seems to be the most rare event that is happening in my simulation.  I was able to quickly generate the 0.75 billion card combinations which is $52 \choose 8$ so I just have to insert the check for the ties and count them up.  I have another simulation running now overnight so I don't want to stress my CPU at $100$% for many hours so I will wait until the first one finishes and then code the 2nd one and report back.  Based on the simulation getting only $29$ out of $10,000,000$, I could think out of $750$ million possible $8$ card hands there should be a little over $2000$ ways to tie.

$UPDATE - 2$ Out of 1 billion simulated hands, I am seeing only $2547$ D/E ties on the $8$th drawn card.  That is the most rare event I see of all the buckets I am viewing.  It is almost as rare as a royal straight flush in a $5$ card poker hand ($5$ cards only).

$UPDATE - 3$  I made a mistake in that to simulate all the possible $8$ card hands to check for a D/E tie on that exact card, it is not just $52 \choose 8$ combinations because order is important, so it is $8$! more than that which is a huge number and too large to easily simulate on a computer.  An example where D and E tie on the 8th card (using C=Club, H=Heart, S=Spade, D=Diamond) is AH,AD,AC,2C,3C,4C,5C,AS.  That completes both the $6$ blacks in a row and quad aces on the $8$th card.  So since $52!$ / $44!$ is such a huge number of hands to simulate/generate (it is over $30$ trillion), probably the best I can do (easily) is just simulate a $7$ card hand, check to make sure neither D nor E won at that point, then draw the 8th card and check if they tied on that card.  Again that is only an approximation but will be faster than drawing up to $28$ cards and checking for $4$ possible winners.  Note that there is no way there can be a tie on the $7$th card because a quad has $2$ of each color card so we would need those plus $6$ in a row of the same color card so that is $8$ cards minimum.

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to a math problem with a ton of computation?

Comment: @DennisMeng I think a computer simulation would be the quickest/easiest way of figuring it out.  Off the top of my head, F sounds easiest to get.

Comment: @JS1 Probably. But I was asking more because I was under the impression that math problems where you just throw computation power (either brain or computer) were considered off-topic.

Comment: @JS1, why would F be the easiest to get when $24$ cards is the minimum for F to win but E can win with as few as $4$ cards and D could win with as few as $6$ cards and all ties involving F are a loss for F?  Out of all $4$ players here, F requires the most cards to win at $24$ minimum.  The average number of cards for a decision (win/tie) might even be less than that since C,D, and E require far fewer cards to possibly win, so on those hands (let's say only $20$ cards are drawn), F cannot win.

Comment: Because in puzzling.se, the more seemingly impossible it is for one event to happen, the more likely it is to be the answer =)

Comment: With the $28$ card (max) restriction, the only way F could win a hand is if the hand stops at either $24, 25, 26, 27$, or $28$ cards and nobody else wins or ties that hand.

Comment: I think what's interesting is that a problem like this can't be done with a computer i think. Because there are $52!$ number of possible decks and no way you can simulate all those decks. As you can see Akiiino uses 1,000,000 but that still only gives an estimation. I wouldn't be surprised if all 4 have actually the same chance of winning.

Comment: I would say if someone simulated 1 billion decisions, there is little chance of getting the winner wrong (assuming the code is correct and the random number generator is fair).  If you have a really fast computer perhaps try 1 trillion.  I strongly doubt all 4 have the same exact chances of winning.

Comment: "Four people, (call them C, D, E and F), decide to play a card game for fun" The real puzzle is why on earth they thought this game would be fun

Comment: The game is almost totally fair (almost equiprobable that any of the 4 will win any hand), and in the shortrun, anyone can get a substantial lead.  So it is fun because of that.

Comment: I voted to keep this closed, but I am very interested in this problem, and all others like it. Try Math.StackExchange, and if you don't get a response there, then try Michael Shackelford's Wizard of Odds website. He answers questions like this and is an expert with plenty of experience. http://wizardofodds.com/ask-the-wizard/

Comment: I tried Math.StackExchange but it got "booted" there too maybe since it is "impossible" to solve mathematically ("on paper") yet I asked a very similar question there and it didn't get booted and I got a lot of views so there is a major inconsistency on these sites and it is unclear what is allowed and what is not.  My question here is a fun exercise which can only really be solved with computer simulation.  It does not directly involve math since it can be solved without using it.  It doesn't make sense to me this question got put on hold.  Look at how many views and responses it got!

Comment: I just want to know what happened to A and B - did they bump them off?

Answer (score 5):

It seems I am too stupid for this site: I haven't been able to post any solution that I made myself; though I can make my computer solve puzzles for me.

Here's Python code that I wrote: it runs a lot of simulations and counts victories for each player as well as losses of everyone (when nobody wins after 28 cards are drawn). A draw adds 1 point to D and E, while victory adds 2 points to the winner.

```
from random import choice


def countWinners(*args):
    return sum(bool(x) for x in args)


deck = []
for a in ['H', 'D', 'C', 'S']:
    for b in xrange(1, 14):
        deck.append((a, b))


results = {'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'Nobody': 0}
games = 1000000
for i in xrange(games):
    C = set()
    D = [0, 0]
    E = {1: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0, 7: 0, 9: 0, 11: 0, 13: 0}
    F = {'R': 0, 'B': 0}

    cards = deck[:]
    cardcount = 0
    if i % 1000 == 0:
            print 1.0*i/games
    while len(C) < 13 and D[1] < 6 and all(x < 4 for x in E.itervalues()) and any(y < 12 for y in F.itervalues()) and cardcount < 29:
        card = choice(cards)
        cards.remove(card)
        cardcount += 1

        C.add(card[1])

        if card[0] in ('C', 'S'):
            if D[0] == 0:
                D[1] += 1
            else:
                D[0] = 0
                D[1] = 1
        if card[0] in ('H', 'D'):
            if D[0] == 1:
                D[1] += 1
            else:
                D[0] = 1
                D[1] = 1

        if card[1] % 2 == 1:
            E[card[1]] += 1

        if card[0] in ('C', 'S'):
            F['B'] += 1
        else:
            F['R'] += 1

    if cardcount == 29:
        results['Nobody'] += 2
    else:
        if countWinners(len(C) == 13, D[1] >= 6, any(x == 4 for x in E.itervalues()), all(y >= 12 for y in F.itervalues())) >= 2:
            results['D'] += 1
            results['E'] += 1
        else:
            if len(C) == 13:
                results['C'] += 2
            if D[1] == 6:
                results['D'] += 2
            if any(x == 4 for x in E.itervalues()):
                results['E'] += 2
            if all(y >= 12 for y in F.itervalues()):
                results['F'] += 2
for player in results.keys():
    print player, 1.0*results[player]/2/games
```

It may be not quite clear, but it seems to work. The interesting thing is that the output is this:

```
C 0.2471
Nobody 0.0186
E 0.242735
D 0.244535
F 0.24703
```

Each player wins in about 24.5% of all games! That looks quite suspicious, I must admit, but I couldn't find any bugs that I didn't fix.

UPD. After running 10.000.000 simulations the results are

```
C 0.2470487
Nobody 0.0184092
E 0.2423495
D 0.2435982
F 0.2485944
```

UPD2. 61 millions in:

```
C 0.247020145161
Nobody 0.0184576290323
E 0.242251653226
D 0.243597201613
F 0.248673354839
```

UPD3. After 130 millions the probabilities are more or less stable around

```
C 0.2469661
Nobody 0.0184452
E 0.2423032
D 0.2435659
F 0.2487196
```

I'm stopping simulations because some much, **much** faster solutions were added and their results seem to be consistent with the ones I've got

Comment: Wow interesting. How long did the 1 million iterations take to run? If a reasonable amount of time, perhaps try 10 million because it seems C and F are "neck and neck". Solving this problem thru simulation relies on a good random number generator and lots of iterations. For example, if you only ran 1000 iterations, the winner might not be C like here. It seems odd and somewhat unpredictable that the "odds are even" when each of the 4 players has much different winning conditions ranging from only 4 cards min needed to as many as 24 cards min needed. Try 1000 and 10,000,000 please if you can

Comment: Also, it is interesting that in about $2$% of the hands, nobody wins!  That is surprising especially when we can go up to $28$ cards drawn and there are $4$ possible ways to win (cuz of $4$ players).  A loss would have to "dodge" all of those winning ways in $28$ cards such as not completing an "odd quad", $17$ or more of 1 color card...

Comment: Having a large # of iterations is important because too few will make someone draw the wrong conclusion.  Worst case is if you play this game manually (or simulate it) only getting $4$ decisions.  It is possible that one player can win all $4$ games and make you think they have a very strong advantage but as we can see, they are all about even.  Even $1000$ decisions is too few and any of the players can be the overall "winner".  Based on the results of Akiiino, it appears C is the winner but it may be too close to call.

Comment: @DavidJames, simulation took about 25 minutes, and results are almost the same, but C is not a winner anymore:

    C: 0.2470487;
    Nobody: 0.0184092;
    E: 0.2423495;
    D: 0.2435982;
    F: 0.2485944;    

I think that at this point it is almost impossible to improve the answer by brute-force simulation: the probabilities are too close to be distinguished in such way. I suppose C and F are winning more often than others, but who is the most probable winner is to be answered by math, not programming

Comment: Using math alone if likely too hard so computers are our only hope.  Getting it exact is not necessary, just getting consistent results is.  For example, if C is the overall winner one time then F then back to C... that is not conclusive.  However if F is always the overall winner then that is (assuming many iterations like at least a few million).  If you ran a simulation overnight and got 1 billion decisions then I would say that is conclusive.  It would be "hard" for a correct simulation to give the wrong results with that many trials.  Any anomalies would get "ironed out".

Comment: @DavidJames, it would take approximately 25*100 = 2500 minutes = 41,66 hours on my pc to run 1 billion simulations – I could launch computations, but don't expect any results in the next 2 days

Comment: I suppose using a compiled language on a fast computer, 1 billion decisions could be gotten in less than 1 hour.  I don't think the results change after about 10 million though so 1 billion is not really necessary unless you want to try it for fun.  I hope it doesn't make your computer crawl so you cannot do anything else on it.  I have a dual core processor (with dual display) so I can run simulations and still be productive with other stuff at the same time on the same computer.

Comment: @DavidJames, I will launch the computations, I think, because it's not a problem to keep it running – I just wanted to let you know how long it can take

Comment: It would be interesting to start with the all the possible $4$ card hands and count up how many are winners then move on the $5$ card hands... up to $28$ cards and eventually we could get an exact answer but an approximation is good enough here.  F is indeed the winner but not by much.  Nice work Akiiino.

Comment: A couple optimization ideas - (1) compute and store the win conditions, then (2) `if sum(winners): if sum(winners)>=2:... else:...`. (3) Check for win condition first, then `elif cardcount==28:results['Nobody'] += 2` and change the loop condition - this eliminates simulating a 29th draw that is never used.

Comment: Another simple tweak might be instead of checking for quads of A,3,5,7,9,J,or K, just pick the 7 highest or lowest ranks which doesn't change the probability but may be a simpler check to code.  Also it may help to cheat slightly by looking at the number of cards drawn so far and reordering the check for C,D,E,and F winning.  For example, if the drawn card count is 6, we should only check for D and/or E winning because C and F cannot possibly win.  However if we know the most probable winner for each card count from 4 to 28, we can have blocks of code to check the winners based on card counts.

Comment: My simulation program has buckets for all the card counts from 4 to 28 so I know which of C,D,E, and F is most likely to win with that card count so in my code, I could do something like "if card count is between 18 and 21, check for winners in this order C, E, D, F".  This is just an example and may not be the proper order.  Even though the percentages are all about the same overall, the winners for C,D,E, and F come on at different times so the card count plays an important role for optimizing the order of the check for winners.  The optimal order may be different for different # of cards.

Comment: @DavidJames changing the order of the check could cause it to run slower - you don't gain much by changing the order, and the additional checks necessary to change the order could easily offset any gain.

Answer (score 1):

After 100,000,000 iterations, I get the following (CIs calculated based on this: http://www.evanmiller.org/statistical-formulas-for-programmers.html#prop_mci):

```
C: 0.246899 - 0.247071
D: 0.24354 - 0.243711
E: 0.242103 - 0.242275
F: 0.24869 - 0.248863
X: 0.018397 - 0.0184508
```

Which corroborates Akiiino's numbers and means that F has a real advantage, although a small one. Code below if you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void report(string name, double x, double z) {
    double n = z / 2;
    double p = x / z;
    double c0 = (p + 2 / n) / (1 + 4 / n);
    double c1 = 2 * sqrt((p * (1 - p) + 1 / n) / n) / (1 + 4 / n);
    cout << name << ": " << (c0 - c1) << " - " << (c0 + c1) << endl;
}

int main() {
    array<int, 52> cards; // rank then suit, alternating colors of suits
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
        cards[i] = i;

    long long c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;

    mt19937_64 rnd(chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    for(long long z = 2, r = 2;; z += 2) {
        shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), rnd);

        array<int, 26> counts = {};

        int dr = 0, db = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 28; ++i) {
            counts[cards[i] % 26] += 1;

            int cs = 1, es = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j) {
                if(counts[j] + counts[j + 13] == 0)
                    cs = 0;
                if(j % 2 == 0 && counts[j] + counts[j + 13] == 4)
                    es = 1;
            }

            if(cards[i] % 26 < 13) {
                dr += 1;
                db = 0;
            } else {
                db += 1;
                dr = 0;
            }
            int ds = (dr >= 6 || db >= 6);

            int fs = 0, fr = 0, fb = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
                fr += counts[j];
            for(int j = 13; j < 26; ++j)
                fb += counts[j];

            fs = (fr >= 12 && fb >= 12);

            if(cs + ds + es + fs > 0) {
                if(cs + ds + es + fs > 1) {
                    d += 1;
                    e += 1;
                } else {
                    c += 2 * cs;
                    d += 2 * ds;
                    e += 2 * es;
                    f += 2 * fs;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if(z == r) {
            cout << (z / 2) << endl;
            report("C", c, z);
            report("D", d, z);
            report("E", e, z);
            report("F", f, z);
            report("X", z - c - d - e - f, z);
            cout << endl;

            r *= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work too.  Computer simulation of the actual game is great for these type of counting problems and one of the few practical solutions.  Perhaps I can encapsulate my simulation for checking and counting winners into a single subroutine and then call it, first simulating all possible 4 card hands, then simulating all possible 5 card hands... and build a table of winners for C,D,E, and F.  That would work when the # of drawn cards is low like single digits but not for something like 20 cards drawn as the number of card combinations is huge.  Simulation of 1 million or more hands is the way!

Comment: A little bit of statistics can make the results of these types of simulations much more robust. With those confidence intervals (assuming I've calculated them correctly) you can say what the chance is that the difference is just due to random luck, and in this case, it's pretty clear that the difference between C and F isn't just luck.

Answer (score 1):

### A fast C program

I'll throw my C program into the mix.  It runs much faster than the Python program from @Akiiino.  I am able to run over 1 million hands per second, and so I ran it for 1 billion hands (taking about 13 minutes).  The program listing is at the end of this answer.  Here are the results:

### The original problem

The original problem did not impose a 28 card limit.  I guessed that F would be the easiest to achieve and I was right:

```
(10 million iterations)
C) 24.9527%
D) 24.5856%
E) 24.5530%
F) 25.9087%
```

### With 28 cards max

With a 28 card limit, the result became closer:

```
(1 billion iterations)
C) 24.6989%
D) 24.3624%
E) 24.2243%
F) 24.8718%
N) 1.8426% (no winner)
```

If someone wants to run my program for even more iterations, feel free to do so.

### So why did I guess F?

Ok so David James asked why did I guess F?  I did some quick calculations (that were admittedly not very precise) to guesstimate the avg card at which each player would win.  Remember, the following is not correct math, it's just what was going through my mind:

### My rough calculations (which were bad)

Player C needs all 13 cards to win.  This is very similar to the [Coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).  If each card were replaced back into the deck, it would take on average 42 cards dealt to win (according to the Wikipedia table).  However, the cards are *not* placed back into the deck, so it takes less cards on average to win.  Still, I figured the number would be closer to 42 than to 26.  I guessed halfway in between so 34.

Player D needs 6 of the same color in a row to win.  The odds of that happening are 1/32, starting at card 6.  It is 1/32 because it is 1/64 chance for 6 reds and 1/64 chance for 6 blacks.  So I figured that D would get the 6 in a row on average at card 38 (start at card 6 and takes 32 cards on average).

Player E wins by getting one of 7 four of a kinds.  The odds of getting a four of a kind for a particular number (such as Ace) with 4 cards is `4/52 * 3/51 * 2/50 * 1/49` which is 1 in 270725.  Given 7 different numbers (A3579JK), the chances are 1 in 38675.  Now I just need to know what number of cards N is it that makes `N C 4` around half that (19337), where `C` is the combination operator.  The answer is between 27 (17550 4-card combos) and 28 (20475 4-card combos).  So I called it 27.5.

Player F wins by getting 12 red and 12 black cards.  Using a [binomial calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx), I was able to determine that with 26 cards, the odds of getting at least a 12/12 split was 44.3%.  With 27 cards, the odds went up to 55.8%.  So the expected win occurs between 26 and 27 cards.  So I called it 26.5.

### The reality

I made a big mistake in calculating player D.  The 6 in a row of a color needs to account for the fact that you aren't putting the card back into the deck.  So after you get 5 in a row of red, the odds of getting a 6th red card is much less than 50%.  My guess for player C was also way off.

I modified my program to find out how many cards on average does it take each person to win:

```
(50 million iterations)
C) 27.997
D) 25.810 (but with a 53.6% of not even winning at all) 
E) 28.904
F) 26.375
```

But even knowing the average card isn't good enough because you also need to take into account the distribution, and also figure out how often there are ties.  Anyways, I don't know of a good way to determine the answer to this problem without a computer simulation.

Here is my program:

### The program listing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DEFAULT_ITERATIONS        1000000
static int simulate(void);
static int deck[52];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int iterations = DEFAULT_ITERATIONS;
    int wins[5] = {0};
    int i       = 0;

    for (i=0;i<52;i++)
        deck[i] = i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (argc > 1)
        iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Each win earns 2 points.  A tie earns 1 point for D and 1 for E.
    // wins[4] is the slot for "no winner".
    for (i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        int winner = simulate();
        if (winner == -1) {
            // It's a tie.  Half point to D an E.
            wins[1]++;
            wins[2]++;
        } else {
            // A sole winner.
            wins[winner]+=2;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("%d) %8d wins out of %8d = %7.4lf%%\n", i, wins[i], 2*iterations,
                ((double) wins[i] * 100.0) / (2*iterations));
    }
    return 0;
}

// Returns winner 0-3, 4 for no winner, or -1 for a tie.
static int simulate(void)
{
    int i;
    int rankBitmap        = 0;
    int redCardsInARow    = 0;
    int blackCardsInARow  = 0;
    int totalReds         = 0;
    int totalBlacks       = 0;
    int rankHistogram[13] = {0};
    int win               = 0;

    // Shuffle deck.
    for (i=0;i<51;i++) {
        int r = rand() % (52 - i);
        int tmp;

        // Swap card i with card i+r.
        tmp       = deck[i];
        deck[i]   = deck[i+r];
        deck[i+r] = tmp;
    }

    // Deal cards one by one, and update win conditions.
    for (i=0;i<28;i++) {
        int card = deck[i];
        int color = card & 1;
        int rank  = card >> 2;

        // C wins if he gets all 13 ranks.
        rankBitmap |= (1 << rank);
        if (rankBitmap == 0x1fff)
            win |= 0x1;

        // D wins by getting 6 red cards or 6 black cards in a row.
        if (color) {
            // Black.
            redCardsInARow = 0;
            if (++blackCardsInARow == 6)
                win |= 0x2;
        } else {
            // Red.
            blackCardsInARow = 0;
            if (++redCardsInARow == 6)
                win |= 0x2;
        }

        // E wins if he gets 4 of a kind of any odd rank (A3579JK) (7 chances).
        if ((rank & 1) == 0) {
            if (++rankHistogram[rank] == 4)
                win |= 0x4;
        }

        // F wins by getting 12 black and 12 red cards.
        if (color)
            totalBlacks++;
        else
            totalReds++;
        if (totalBlacks >= 12 && totalReds >= 12)

            win |= 0x8;

        if (win != 0)
            break;
    }
    // If we dealt 28 cards, there must not be a winner.
    if (i == 28)
        return 4;
    switch (win) {
        case 0x1: return 0;
        case 0x2: return 1;
        case 0x4: return 2;
        case 0x8: return 3;
        default: return -1; // Must be a tie.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work JS1.  This question was an exercise in accurate programming and to illustrate how the # of decisions is important to get correct results.  Note that if you only run about 100,000 decisions of less, you may get the wrong "winner" such as C but in the longrun, F is actually the winner. Kudos to JS1 for "guessing" (educated) the correct answer of F. I tried to throw him off by pointing out things like F needs the most cards of all 4 players to even have a chance at winning but his "pre-analysis" was good enough to get it right.1 million or more decisions should give correct answer of F.

Comment: It might be fun to really optimize this simulation for speed and then try something like 1 trillion decisions.  Things to "prune" would be don't even check for C winning unless 13+ cards are dealt.  Same with F but don't check below 24 cards dealt....  If someone could break this up into chunks such as all possible 4 card hands, all possible 5 card hands... and count up the winners, that would be a super solution and 100% accurate. The sum of those all the up to 28 drawn cards is about 1.5 quadrillion so 1 computer may not be enough unless some clever optimizations are done but we know F wins.

Comment: Change your program to calculate the average # of drawn cards for ANY win (or tie).  You can include no wins as well as it doesn't change the answer much (perhaps by half a card).  I am showing under 21 cards as the average for a decision.  Your numbers for ave # of cards for C,D,E, and F are higher because that is assuming no competition but they all share the same cards so the 26.5 or so average of the 4 players solo drops to about 21 when they all play together but that makes sense because it is easier for someone to win (or tie) if all 4 win conditions are active simultaneously.

Comment: JS1 - What computer did you run the simulation on where you are getting over $1$ million decisions per second?  Also, can you try some register variable(s) in c to see if that helps speed things up?  It seems like with some optimizations, you might be able to get close to $100$ billion decisions overnight (in $8$ to $10$ hours) and post the results.

Comment: @DavidJames It was a Windows 7 32-bit 3.2 GHz Core i5.  I could get a lot more speed by using threads for parallel execution (4 cores = 4x speed).  But I just whipped this program together in a hurry so I didn't bother.  I doubt the results would change too much.  Plus I would use a better rng because the system rand() would start to cycle at 2^32 random numbers.

Comment: Wow I only have $3.06$ Ghz (per core) dual core Intel processor on XP SP3 ($32$ bit) but it runs at $50$% on both cores when I run the simulation which is good because that leaves me power to do other things I need to do on the same computer so as I am typing this now, I am running $1$ billion hands to check how rare the D/E tie is for exactly $8$ cards out of $1$ billion hands.  I want to confirm that is the most rare even that actually happens in the game.  Fun stuff.

Answer (score 1):

### Exact odds of D and E tying on the eighth card

This seemed like a separate question so I'm giving an answer just for this part of it.  You can count exactly how many hands will cause D and E to tie on the eighth card dealt.

For the first card, there are 28 cards that are part of the 4 of a kinds.  For the second card, the card dealt must be the same rank and color as the first card, meaning there is only one possible card.  Example: first card is AS, second card must be AC.  Therefore, the first 2 cards have 28 possibilities.

The next 6 cards must all be of the opposite color to the first two cards.  In addition, one of the first five and also the last of these 6 cards must match the rank of the first two cards.

To find out how many possibilities there are, first consider the 4 cards that are *not* part of the 4 of a kind.  There are `24 C 4` ways of choosing these four cards, times `4!` ways of ordering them.

To those 4 cards, one of the matching ranked cards must be added to make the first five cards.  That matching card can be placed in one of 5 positions.  In other words, the 4 nonmatching cards plus the one matching card can have `5!` possible orderings.

Finally, the two matching cards can be swapped, doubling the number of ways the last 6 cards can be made.  The total is now:

```
28 * 24C4 * 5! * 2 = 71406720 possibilities
```

Out of:

```
52! / 44! = 3.034e13 total possibilities
```

Which is approximately:

```
 1 in 424923 chance
```

You could also calculate it exactly if you wanted to.

Comment: I ran another simulation of $1$ billion $8$ card hands and according to your formula, I should have gotten $2353.37$ "winners".  My results were $2334$ winners which is very close (within $1$%).  I was curious about this case because it is the most rare event of all the events I have buckets to count up (wins & ties for all different card counts).

Comment: To put that "rareness" into perspective, it is about $11$ times as rare as getting an "odd quad" dealt in the first $4$ cards.  My simulation told me that happened $25,532$ times out of 1 billion hands.

Comment: @DavidJames "Odd quad": 28*3*2*1 chances out of 52*51*50*49 total = 25856.5 expected out of 1 billion hands.

Comment: Maybe why our results are about $1$% off is because I first checked if either D or E won at $7$ cards dealt before I then process the $8$th card and check for a tie.  If I didn't do that check, my numbers would have been slightly higher.

Comment: This "puzzle" is interesting because it is not obvious to someone trying to solve it who has the advantage. Someone could "argue" any of C,D,E, or F has the advantage and it would be hard to dispute without actually running a computer simulation of 1 million or more decisions. Just playing the game with a deck of cards wont tell you the long term winner. The only "bias" I see that might "give away" that F may have an advantage is that the first $12$ cards are all guaranteed good cards for F whereas that is not true for any other player but amazingly they all have about identical probabilities.

Comment: I like the humorous comment about the equal probabilities being suspicious.  It is a puzzle which means that some thought was given to it ahead of time.  If I just picked 4 "random" conditions then chances are very high someone would be an "easy" winner and it wouldn't be as interesting. The problem is well constructed because it is not obvious who the winner is and it is not obvious that they all have about an equal chance.  In the shortrun, anyone could win, even 5 or more games (hands) in a row. Computer simulation of 1 million of more hands seems to be required to solve this, no other way.

Comment: Over 300 views and then they decide it is "off topic"?  A puzzle is a game, problem, or toy that tests a person's ingenuity or knowledge (according to Wikipedia).  This is a problem that tests a person simulation ability and ability to understand the problem correctly.  It is a very interesting problem for several reasons... 1) because it cannot be done "on paper" with mathematics because it is too tedious.  2) because of the surprising results of almost equal probability.  It should be taken off hold so other people can contribute other insight and share with viewers.  I vote to reinstate!

Comment: Before  the advent of computers, perhaps this problem was unsolvable because it would take too much work on paper to solve.  Now with fast computers, over 1 million hands can be simulated in 1 second and give very good approximations and the correct winner (F).  Considering what a "bear" this would be on paper, that is impressive (to me).